# Database cannot be opened. It is in the middle of a restore?

Tags: sql-server, log-shipping

I've set up log shipping using standby mode （The "Disconnect users in the database when restoring backups" is unchecked).

I tested running the following code on secondary server/database.

```
declare @a int
while 1=1
begin
  select @a = count(*) from ....
end
```

However, the code stops with the following error when log shipping restore job start to run.

> Database cannot be opened. It is in the middle of a restore.

How to avoid the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is kind of how log shipping *has* to work. You need exclusive access to a database to apply a log backup, which means your script has to set the database to single_user or otherwise evict all the users before it can apply the log backup(s).

Some workarounds:

1. Schedule your restores for outside of business hours, and let them continue querying stale data in the meantime.
2. Queue up multiple log backups and apply them, say, every hour or every two hours. Users get periodic updates throughout the day, with interruptions less frequent than the log backup schedule on the primary.
3. Don't force your script to kick users out. This means the log restore will wait and wait and wait until there are no active connections to the database. I've never actually tried this, and its feasibility really depends on how active your secondary is.
4. Have multiple secondaries and cycle through them. [I've written pretty extensively about this approach](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/10/sql-performance/readable-secondaries-on-a-budget).

Comment: It seems it may not be a great idea to use log shipping for a secondary reporting server in a production environment.

Comment: @u23432534 Out of the box, yep, I tend to agree. But it can work great for people willing to do a bit of work (or allow users to be interrupted) instead of paying for more robust solutions like Mirroring + Snapshots (pre-2012) and Availability Groups (2012+). If you have Enterprise Edition then, by all means, log shipping is not the optimal choice.

Comment: Is it possible to set up mirroring to transfer the changes over FTP (there is no direct TCP connection between the servers). I know log shipping can be configured to send the backup files that way.

Comment: No, mirroring won't do that, but there are probably a dozen or more ways to solve that problem **outside** of SQL Server.

Comment: Curiously, what's other options (inside or outside of SQL server)? Can merge replication do this?

Comment: Shipping log backups using things like running `ftp` at the command line, PowerShell, C#, etc.

Comment: ftp, PowerShell, C#, etc., still need to work with something that tracks the changes in SQL server?

Comment: Wow, this is going all over the place. Transaction logs already *have* all the changes, so log shipping is the way to do it if you don't have direct access to the server. Replication, mirroring, Availability Groups, etc. are simply not going to work over FTP.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to check if there is any perfect solution which doesn't have the problem of log shipping killing running query when restoring and can be over FTP.

Answer (score 2):

Well the first thing I would check is if the database is actually restoring, this is the query I use to report on the status.

```
SELECT session_id AS SPID
          ,command
          ,a.TEXT AS Query
          ,start_time
          ,percent_complete
          ,dateadd(second, estimated_completion_time / 1000, getdate()) AS estimated_completion_time
    FROM sys.dm_exec_requests r
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) a
    WHERE r.command IN ('BACKUP DATABASE','RESTORE DATABASE')
```

Comment: Thanks for the query, but what do I do if it's not actually restoring? The SSMS UI says my database restoring in the Object Explorer. How do I get back access to it?